# why auto type cannot coexist with other build-in type in for statement C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, auto

Look at following code:

```
vector<int> ivec(10);
for (auto it = ivec.begin(), int i = 0; it != ivec.end(); it++)
{
  //body;
}
```

It cannot compile successfully. And it would be ok when I use other build-in types instead **auto**. For example:

```
for (int i = 0, double d = 1.0; i < d; i++)
 {
   //body
 }
```

thanks.

Comment: Are you sure, you compile with C++11 support? Before that, auto was a keyword with a different meaning, which nobody ever used.

Comment: Also your second example does not compile neither with gcc nor clang

Comment: Well, even the second `for` would NOT compile. **Please try compiling and verify it before posting your question based on *false* assumption.**

Comment: A for loop can only have one type in the init-statement.

Comment: @Nawaz when I write **second** `for` in visual studio it does not report any problem. However, running it, it failed. Now I know, for loop could only have one type in the init-statement.

Comment: @sydridgm: "writing" is not same as "compiling"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't compile because it's a syntax error to declare more than one type in a `for` loop.

Im guessing you're looking to iterate while tracking the index?

here's one of many ways to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    vector<int> ivec { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    for (auto p = make_pair(ivec.begin(), 0) ; 
         p.first != ivec.end() ; 
         ++p.first, ++p.second)
    {
        cout << "index is " << p.second;
        cout << " value is " << *(p.first) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
index is 0 value is 10
index is 1 value is 9
index is 2 value is 8
index is 3 value is 7
index is 4 value is 6
index is 5 value is 5
index is 6 value is 4
index is 7 value is 3
index is 8 value is 2
index is 9 value is 1
```

(note the use of pre-increment to prevent un-necessary copies of your iterator)